# Story about a man who chose to be transformed to a plant

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a text on my Fiction course back when I was at the University. It is about a person who chose to undergo trans-species change (I am sure that that is not the term, but I hope you get the idea). His end state is something that resembles a plant. I vaguely remember how it goes, but the man currently is undergoing the procedure. One scene is about how he felt when his feet started growing roots.

Initially, I thought it was Ursula K Le Guin but the comments below made me doubt if I remembered it correctly. Can anyone help me remember the title?

Comment: I've read a lot of Le Guin's work but this really doesn't sound like her; she didn't write much about non-humanoids that I recall.

Comment: Trans-species change is a common theme in Iain M Banks's Culture novels, could it be one of those?

Comment: I might have misremembered it then.

Comment: Probably not [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83291/anyone-know-the-title-of-a-sci-fi-short-story-where-man-becomes-a-plant); not by Ursula K. Le Guin, and the guy does not exactly *choose* to turn into a plant.

Comment: @JoeL. She did, however, write about Haleth (Ogion's teacher) turning into ***SPOILER SPOILER SPOILER***. In *Tales From Earthsea*.

Comment: @gelolopez You may not have misremembered! I have an Ursula le Guin fan here who says UlG did write such a story but can't remember the title.

Comment: @randal'thor this has been so elusive to me. I lost my copy of the text and I have read it about 6 years ago. That story opened my mind about changing gender and here I am seriously contemplating to undergo surgery.

Comment: I was thinking this might be Ursula K. Le Guin's "Olders": http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?44686 but it's not exactly his choice: "A doctor accompanies a wounded man back to his home island. The man never wakes from his comma, but instead begins to turn into a tree, as is common for people of his line" http://bethreadsbooks.blogspot.bg/2013/05/unlocking-air_30.html

Comment: In "Trash Sex Magic" by Jennifer Stevenson a man finds himself growing roots (https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/729757.Trash_Sex_Magic) but it's a short novel, not a short story.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember a Le Guin story on that subject, but Clifford D. Simak wrote a great story on the topic called "Desertion." Maybe that was it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFFSE!  Could you please add a little more detail on the story 'Desertion' that you've identified to help the OP determine whether that might be it?  Thanks!

Comment: "Desertion" is a classic, but I don't think that's it, because the end state in "Desertion" does not resemble a plant.

Comment: Right, my mistake...the man in the Simak story becomes an animal species, not a plant one. Le Guin did write a story called "Vaster than Empires, and More Slow" in which a man willingly chooses to mentally unite himself with a vast forest, but as far as I recall there was nothing about him actually becoming a plant.

Comment: Here's a quote from "Vaster Than Empires and More Slow": ...And before it panicked it had a—there was a serenity. I couldn't take it in, then, I didn't realize how big it was. To know the whole daylight, after all, and the whole night. All the winds and the lulls together. The winter stars and the summer stars at the same time. To have roots, and no enemies. To be entire. Do you see? No invasion. No others. To be whole ..." Look familiar?

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer, which I hope someone can flesh-out. I will give what detail I can.

The story you are after sounds like one that I read perhaps as long as 30 years ago. I could have sworn it was by James Blish, but I can’t find it in any of my own Blish collections.

I’m not certain of the initial setup, but I *think* that it involves a newly-discovered planet, and an explorer helping a *young* humanoid native to escape from something or someone.  The native goes along with this quite happily, I think out of cooperative innocence.

At the climax they are running through some open landscape, which I think must involve crossing a stream or river. The story ends with the native responding to contact with water by coming to a halt and reflexively bending over to grab his own ankles: his body quickly fuses into this new shape.  His ‘feet’ do what they were going to do all along, and put down roots.  The natural mature stage of his existence is to stop being a mobile ‘animal’ and become a ‘plant’. I suppose his mobile form achieves something a bit like thistledown, and once he reaches a suitable place to germinate (or whatever we should call it) its job is done.

The ‘rescuer’ (or perhaps just the reader, if I have invented this rescue story) suddenly has to realise that he or she was massively misinterpreting an alien life cycle that’s actually fairly straightforward once you have an informed perspective on it.  Classic hard-and-soft sf.

Comment: I don't know if it's what the OP is looking for, but the story you are thinking of is ["Unhuman Sacrifice"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55668) by [Katherine MacLean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katherine_MacLean), which was identified as the answer to [this old question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114963/what-is-the-title-of-a-short-story-about-boy-who-becomes-a-tree) and [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64601/short-story-man-rescues-alien-from-cruel-hanging-ceremony-but-alien-turns-into).

Comment: @user14111 Thank you!  That was driving me mad.  Not Blish, then.  Even more oddly, it's in the _brilliant_ anthology _Spectrum_ (eds Kingsley Amis and Robert Conquest, 1961) that I have been using recently as an example in university lectures... but in wrestling with this question I never made the connection.  The lecture thing was about various attempts to accept or promote sf as serious literature, which was Amis's purpose. Your information reminds me of why I had remembered _Spectrum_ as such a significant publishing event in the first place! I haven't _read_ it in years... obviously...

Answer (score 0):

I read all the previously unread short stories that were in the answers to [Sci-Fi Short Story Where Man Becomes a Plant](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83291/sci-fi-short-story-where-man-becomes-a-plant) this question out of interest.

They each answer different forum questions (which have links to other related, not always duplicate, questions). But none exactly match the question description of someone deliberately undergoing a procedure *and* feeling his feet grow roots.

It also links to [this Q&A](https://ask.metafilter.com/195379/Help-me-ID-this-SF-story) which has interesting answers to a related but slightly different question.

In ["Dendrocalalia" by Kobo Abe](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?785037), the man transforming into a plant has awareness of it:

> This time he was acutely conscious of the process of transformation.

The story is in ["Beyond the Curve" by Kobo Abe](https://archive.org/details/beyondcurve00abek/mode/2up).

In this story, the main character does seem to be choosing, or more like giving in to, a procedure, but in scanning it again I don’t remember any reference to how he felt when his feet grew roots.

In ["Piper in the Woods" by Philip K. Dick](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/32832/32832-h/32832-h.htm), the man also seems to be choosing his fate, and has awareness of how the change feels, and it does mention the dirt feeling warm to him, but not quite the question description of feeling his feet grow roots.

> When the dirt was spread out on the floor he sat down in the middle of it. He stretched himself out, leaning back. When he was fully comfortable he folded his hands across his chest and closed his eyes. So much work to do—But later on, of course. Tomorrow. How warm the dirt was.…

In [“Whatever Became of the McGowans?” by Michael G. Coney](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v30n02_1970-05/page/n110/mode/1up?view=theater)
, there is an even more vivid description of how the rootlets on the man’s feet feel:

> At last the tendrils on his feet probed moisture below the surface and the fluid rose into his body, satisfying a craving that had possessed him for days. Once again contentment stole through his senses and he felt his heart slow until it became an occasional spasmodic flicker.

*But* this metamorphosis happens to an entire Earth family on an alien planet, and it is not a “procedure” but the effects of that world, and they neither agree to it nor do humans yet have much medical knowledge  about it.

In Katherine Maclean’s “Unhuman Sacrifice”, the young native of an alien (to humans) world experiences the change of life natural to his species, of changing from a sentient plantlike humanoid to a sessile, rooted, simple plant.

But there is no procedure and no agreeing to it, or again of even knowing about it. (Which is the plot twist.)

I purchased ["I, Tree" by Melvin C. Duncan](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/44802237-the-haunted-mansion-hey-paper-boy-i-tree-out-of-the-blue) to read that story.

It is told in the first person by a sentient tree that sees earth upheavals, interstellar visitor ships, and climactic changes over hundreds of thousands of years. Its thoughts include the thoughts of a human who died near the tree and nourished its roots. It thinks in distress,

> “This can’t be! I’m a man! I can’t stand here on this hill with my feet buried in the dirt!”

But otherwise not a match for the question details.

Keith Laumer’s “Hybrid” is told in the third person from the point of view of a sentient tree that comes to an agreement with a human about its propagation. It’s an engaging story, but not a match for the question.

The two closest possible matches to the question details seem to be “Dendrocalalia” and “Piper in the Woods”. It would be interesting to find out whether you were remembering one of those stories, or if none match and there is yet another human-to-plant-metamorphosis story out there.