# astronauts step on new planet, begin growing tree roots and limbs

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This story was illustrated on the cover of a sci-fi magazine in the 60s. 
The illustration shows 2 astronauts in NASA Gemini-style space suits.  They are struggling as their feet grow roots and anchor them to the ground and their arms sprout tree limbs.

Comment: Can you recall anything about the plot of the story?

Comment: I'm afraid not, sorry.

Comment: I recall something similar, told from the point of view of a young native "person" on the planet.  The culture is primitive/subsistence level and during the rainy season they have a taboo against stepping on bare ground.  The young native does this accidentally and immediately sprouts roots and becomes a tree. In the last seconds of conscious thought he realizes this is his species' destiny, and the taboo was devised by the "sentient" lifecycle phase to prevent the conversion.  This may not be the same story as I don't recall any astronauts visiting.  That's all I remember.

Comment: @JimGarrison You're probably thinking of Katherine MacLean's ["Unhuman Sacrifice"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55668) which was the answer to [this old question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114963/what-is-the-title-of-a-short-story-about-boy-who-becomes-a-tree). The story is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v62n03_1958-11_EXciter-LennyS#page/n99/mode/2up), click [here](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v62n03_1958-11_EXciter-LennyS) for download options.

Answer (score 4):

Are you thinking of [this cover](http://www.philsp.com/data/images/f/fantastic_196212.jpg)

[image]

by artist [Robert Adragna](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?26412) ([www.robertadragna.com](http://www.robertadragna.com/)) from [*Fantastic Stories of Imagination*, December 1962](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58359+c)? There are three astronauts instead of two, and their suits don't look all that much like [Gemini space suits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemini_space_suit), but they are definitely "struggling as their feet grow roots and anchor them to the ground and their arms sprout tree limbs."

The picture illustrates the short story ["Cocoon"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57896) by [Keith Laumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Laumer), which you can read at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantastic_v11n12_1962-12#page/n29/mode/2up) (click [here](https://archive.org/details/Fantastic_v11n12_1962-12) for download options). The illustration is symbolic; there is no new planet in the story, no space suits, no astronauts, no tree roots or branches growing from people.

The same painting was later used for [the cover](https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/0/01/TRNSFRMTNS2005.jpg) of [*Transformations: The Story of the Science Fiction Magazines from 1950 to 1970*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?73992) by [Mike Ashley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Ashley_%28writer%29).

Comment: Good show sir! I thought this one would go un-answered but I think you nailed it.

Comment: I hope the OP comes back and lets us know, one way or the other.