# First contact with aliens who have not fallen into original sin

Tags: story-identification, aliens, religion

I read the story in the 1970s in translation.
Aliens land, meet a priest living as hermit, who talks and tries to instruct them in the faith. Everything seems to be going fine, until he reaches the part of Adam eating from the tree and falling into sin. Then the aliens depart, horrified, as in their world the tree still stands in the garden, untouched...
As I am a priest, I would like very much to find again that story...

Comment: Welcome! What kind of story was it -- a short story, novel, etc.? And what language was it translated to/from?

Comment: Oh, that's really not the ending I expected from the intro...

Comment: @DavidW You were thinking "A Case of Conscience" too?

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez Actually I was thinking of Harrison's "The Streets of Ashkelon," where the priest gets crucified.

Comment: I was thinking of "Unhuman Sacrifice" by Katherine MacLean, which also involves a missionary preaching to aliens, see [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64601).

Comment: [*Perelandra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perelandra)? (Second book of Lewis' [*Space Trilogy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Trilogy))

Comment: @Lexible It would have to be quite badly misremembered if this refers to *Perelandra*. Surely there's a decent number of sci-fi stories which involve the "original sin" idea in some way.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Of course… plenty of folks mix things up in memory. :)

Comment: I think it's worth noting that unlike "Perelandra", "A Case of Conscience", "The Streets of Ashkelon" and many others,  the aliens are visiting Earth, and not the other way around

Comment: Maybe this, but it is not a story but a novel: The Undying from Tale of the Unwithering Realm. They come from the alternate Earth called "Cainem", where humanity was never exiled from the Garden of Eden, and so they cannot ever die—they regenerate all injury and can reassemble their bodies when dismembered. This is not necessarily a good thing; there's a reason they're called "Those Who Seek Death in Vain".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one? Not on Earth but on Mars: ["In This Sign..."](https://archive.org/details/Imagination_v02n02_1951-04_cape1736/page/n55/mode/2up) by Ray Bradbury? (Later retitled "The Fire Balloons".)

The Old Martians are spherical; Father Peregrine is trying to introduce them to Christianity.

> Looking back, Father Peregrine saw the blue fires burning. No, he thought, we couldn’t build a church for the likes of you. You’re Beauty itself. What church could compete with the fireworks of the pure soul?

Comment: Eh, this is a bad fit. Not on Earth and also no "horrified" ending. I should delete this.