# Alien rite, teens tied in trees

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, first-contact

After a family discussion we've thought of another memorable but unidentified old short story.

Some astronauts land on a shrubby planet where there are humanoid people with a simple civilization, culture and religion.

The native people are friendly and the visitors befriend some children, especially one helpful teenage boy.

They discover that the native religion demands that, during the rainy season, adolescents be suspended for several days and nights, feet-upward, in trees.

This is a weird ancient rite of passage. The elders can't/won't explain why it's always been done. And it's their friend's turn this year.

The astronauts notice that post-rite adults look thin, wrinkled and unhealthy. Probably from the trauma? They denounce the custom as cruel and prevent the teen children from taking part, despite their elders' protests.

So, the rains come, flooding the village.

The visitors are horrified to see:

> The teenagers' muddy feet sprout roots and embed themselves in the earth. Overnight the adolescents turn into shrubs - non-sentient shrubs. They are effectively dead as people.

> This is part of the natural life cycle and the astronauts now realise the ritual was necessary to allow the people to remain sentient long enough to actually develop any civilization and culture.

The moral is don't condemn what you don't understand.

Ring any bells?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64601/short-story-man-rescues-alien-from-cruel-hanging-ceremony-but-alien-turns-into/64695#64695

Comment: If it's the same as [Short story: man rescues alien from cruel hanging ceremony, but alien turns into a shrub](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64601/short-story-man-rescues-alien-from-cruel-hanging-ceremony-but-alien-turns-into) please let us know so we can mark this as a duplicate. Thanks :-)

Comment: Yep, that's it. I didn't notice this one was already answered. Thought it was too obscure and seems my memory of it was poor. Sorry.

Comment: There's no need to delete this, closing as a dupe is fine and what it's for. It's a good description as well so worthy of the upvote from myself!